# MATLAB plotting data of continuos dates alongwith observed data of specific dates

Tags: matlab, date, plot

I have simulated daily data corresponding to continuos dates but my observed data is only for some specific dates. How can i plot the continuos simulated data and insert observed data for specific dates on same plot in MATLAB. For example 01-01-05 date to 31-12-05 continuos simulated data and observed data only for 08-01-05, 08-04-05, 25-08-05, 03-11-05 specific dates.

Answer (score 0):

You want to have a look at the description of ticklabels:
https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/change-tick-marks-and-tick-labels-of-graph-1.html

You need to specify for which x-positions (xticks) you want to provide labels, and then use xticks and xticklabels together, like here:

```
x = rand(1, 100);
plot(x);
xticks(0:20:100);
labels = datestr(sort(rand(10,1)*now),2);
xticklabels(labels);
```

With the optional xtickangle you can slightly tilt the labels to create a nicer view of them and/or provide more

```
xtickangle(45);
```